# Implement addDiscount method that gets DiscountData as input to store it in the subscription object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following two classes. I need to Implement a method in the second class namely addDiscount that gets DiscountData as input to store it in the subscription object.

I am guessing I need to use an arraylist here? If so, how?

DiscountData Class:

```
class DiscountData {
    private int value;
    private int length;

public DiscountData(int value, int length) {
    this.value = value;
    this.length = length;
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getLength() {
    return this.length;
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}
}
```

Subscription class:

```
public class Subscription {
    public void addDiscount(DiscountData discountData) {
    // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smth like this:

```
public class Subscription {
    private List<DiscountData> data = new ArrayList<DiscountData>();

    public void addDiscount(DiscountData discountData) {
       data.add(discountData);
    }
}
```